# Merge two arrays based on common key, keeping unmatched values

Tags: json, bash, join, jq

Given this data I am trying to return the `servers` array with any matches from `groups` array based on `s_Group` value.  However `group_by(s_Group)` only returns those common to both arrays (with one extraneous non-match I cannot explain).  It might be worth mentioning this is being done in a bash script so I am game to break the arrays into separate files and/or multiple steps if that makes things easier.

**EDIT**: I should have specified I want all the attributes from `groups` pulled into the new `servers` elements where a match occurs.  Apologies for not making that clear.  Adding a "desired output".

input data:

```
{
    "servers": [
        {
            "location": "srv_apc1",
            "f_Group": "auc-1"
        },
        {
            "location": "srv_apc2",
            "f_Group": "auc-1",
            "c_Group": "c1"
        },
        {
            "location": "srv_apc3",
            "f_Group": "auc-1",
            "c_Group": "c2"
        },
        {
            "location": "srv_apc4",
            "f_Group": "auc-1",
            "c_Group": "c3"
        },
        {
            "location": "srv_wc1",
            "s_Group": "cb-1"
        },
        {
            "location": "srv_wc2",
            "s_Group": "cb-2"
        },
        {
            "location": "srv_wc3",
            "s_Group": "cb-3"
        },
        {
            "location": "srv_wc4",
            "s_Group": "cb-4"
        }
    ],
    "groups": [
        {
            "s_Group": "cb-1",
            "options": [
                "opt1",
                "opt3",
                "opt5",
                "home"
            ]
        },
        {
            "s_Group": "cb-2",
            "options": [
                "opt2",
                "opt4",
                "opt6",
                "home"
            ]
        },
        {
            "s_Group": "cb-3",
            "options": [
                "opt7",
                "opt8",
                "opt9",
                "home",
                "print"
            ]
        },
        {
            "s_Group": "cb-4",
            "options": [
                "ems99",
                "erec98",
                "expr-77",
                "home"
        ]
        },
        {
            "s_Group": "extra-99",
            "options": [
                "conf1",
                "ems34",
                "erec1",
                "home",
                "chec99",
                "franT"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

jq:

```
.servers + .groups | group_by(.s_Group) | map(add)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/VGgahOvwLvG)

desired output:

```
{
    "servers": [
        [
            {
                "location": "srv_apc1",
                "f_Group": "auc-1"
            },
            {
                "location": "srv_apc2",
                "f_Group": "auc-1",
                "c_Group": "c1"
            },
            {
                "location": "srv_apc3",
                "f_Group": "auc-1",
                "c_Group": "c2"
            },
            {
                "location": "srv_apc4",
                "f_Group": "auc-1",
                "c_Group": "c3"
            },
            {
                "location": "srv_wc1",
                "s_Group": "cb-1",
                "options": [
                    "opt1",
                    "opt3",
                    "opt5",
                    "home"
                ]
            },
            {
                "location": "srv_wc2",
                "s_Group": "cb-2",
                "options": [
                    "opt2",
                    "opt4",
                    "opt6",
                    "home"
                ]
            },
            {
                "location": "srv_wc3",
                "s_Group": "cb-3",
                "options": [
                    "opt7",
                    "opt8",
                    "opt9",
                    "home",
                    "print"
                ]
            },
            {
                "location": "srv_wc4",
                "s_Group": "cb-4",
                "options": [
                    "ems99",
                    "erec98",
                    "expr-77",
                    "home"
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please adhere to the [mcve] guidelines.  In particular, the example should be *m*inimal, and the expected output should be shown.

Comment: Thanks for adding the expected output. However, it neither corresponds exactly to the stated requirements (in the expected output, .servers is an array consisting of a single array); nor does it correspond exactly to the given input (e.g. the latter does not have "ems99"). Please clarify or fix.

Answer (score 1):

Everything can be done with one invocation of jq. If I understand the requirements correctly, you could use the following jq program:

```
  INDEX(.groups[] | select(.s_Group); .s_Group) as $dict
  | .servers |= map( . + $dict[.s_Group // ""]) 
  | {servers : [.servers] }
```

This returns the desired output as shown except for the obvious discrepancy relative to "s_Group": "cb-4".

Comment: I omitted the fact I want the groups data pulled into the new servers elements.  Amended the question.

Comment: Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN` with an `INDEX` on the `.servers` items:

```bash
jq '{servers: [JOIN(
  INDEX(.groups[]; .s_Group); .servers[]; .s_Group // empty; add
)]}'
```

```json
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "location": "srv_apc1",
      "f_Group": "auc-1"
    },
    {
      "location": "srv_apc2",
      "f_Group": "auc-1",
      "c_Group": "c1"
    },
    {
      "location": "srv_apc3",
      "f_Group": "auc-1",
      "c_Group": "c2"
    },
    {
      "location": "srv_apc4",
      "f_Group": "auc-1",
      "c_Group": "c3"
    },
    {
      "location": "srv_wc1",
      "s_Group": "cb-1",
      "options": [
        "opt1",
        "opt3",
        "opt5",
        "home"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "srv_wc2",
      "s_Group": "cb-2",
      "options": [
        "opt2",
        "opt4",
        "opt6",
        "home"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "srv_wc3",
      "s_Group": "cb-3",
      "options": [
        "opt7",
        "opt8",
        "opt9",
        "home",
        "print"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "srv_wc4",
      "s_Group": "cb-4",
      "options": [
        "emsar",
        "ereceipt",
        "expressmtreceive",
        "home",
        "mtagentlookup",
        "mtreceive",
        "mtstatus"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IY_KWuOPB4P)

Comment: I omitted the fact I want the groups data pulled into the new servers elements.  Amended the question.

Comment: @JimHastings I have updated my response by adding `{servers: (…)}` around the second line, which wraps the original output (which was an array) into the `servers` field of a new object. If you want an additional pairs of array brackets around that original array (as currently present in your updated desired ouput), change the parens to brackets as in `{servers: […]}`.

Comment: pmf,
This concats the group data to the end of the server data.  I'm looking to get them merged.  See the 'desired output'  I amended to the question.

Comment: @JimHastings That's a whole different story. You can use `JOIN` and `INDEX` as shown in my update. Again, add the extra array brackets, if needed.